# How to resize shapes with stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, resize

I have this logo with two ellipses and multiple line segments.

[image: original logo]

The ellipses have 5pt strokes on them, no fill and the line segments are 3 pt, no fill. I placed the .ai file into another file and tried to resize it down to fit a business card, only to come upon this:

[image: logo that needs to be fixed]

Now the shapes look like they have twice the stroke that they had before. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Edit > Preferences > General**, and make sure **the Scale Strokes & Effects is selected**. By default this is unchecked in Adobe Illustrator.
Now scale your object up or down it will keep its ratio.

or You can Expend your Object, Go to **Object > Expand** and from the popup menu check **Fill** and **Stroke** and Hit **OK** But I do not recommend this method.

Comment: Another place to change this setting is in the fully expanded "Transform" palette, when you have a selection. Yet another way is to double-click the "scale" tool (without a selection), make the change and hit OK.