# How to shrink vector object without distorting it in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am working on a logo.whenever i am shrinking the vector it seems like stroke has increase,but actually it haven't.
if any body can help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64855/how-to-resize-shapes-with-stroke/64857#64857 This can help

Answer (score 1):

When you resize the logo, Illustrator recalculates the new stroke based on the new resolution to retain its exact dimensions. ideally if you select the vector, Click on the **Object** Menu and select **Expand**, this will expand the strokes into paths. Re-sizing the object then retains the exact stroke to object ratio. *remember to select Stroke in the dialog pop up*

However the stroke loses its properties as becomes a path object.